# Installing Older Versions of Git

Tags: c, git, github

I am running Mac OS 10.7.5, and I was wondering how I can install an older version of git. Also, which version do people recommend? Since I get C files if I download an older version, do I run them with my bash profile?

Comment: Latest version can be installed on 10.7 with Brew http://brew.sh/. Why would you want an older git version?

Comment: Re "which version people recommend", Any reason to believe the answer is anything but "the latest version"?

Comment: Re "Since I get C files if I download an older version, do I run them with my bash profile?", You can't run C files; they must be compiled into an executable program.

Comment: The 4 last binaries releases for mac os are available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/?source=navbar